# Performance Issue: Lookup sub-value of python dictionary if it is matching another value

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary-comprehension

I have a python dictionary as follows. Same way, dictionary might have 2 comma separate values for 'Var'(i.e. Dep1,Dep2) and then their respective SubValue (ABC1||A1B1||B1C1, ABC2||A2B2||B2C2).

I'm trying to extract value A1B1 (or A1B1 and B1C1 if there are two Var) with a match of mainValue 'ABC1' and prefix of SubVal 'ABC1'.

```
ld = { 'id' : 0
      'Var': 'Dep1'
      'SubVal': 'ABC1||A1B1,ABC2||A2B2,ABC3||A3B3',
      'MainValue': 'ABC1'}
```

So far I tried splitting Subval into list (splitting by comma) and then convert each pair (|| separated) into another dictionary and then looking up the match. 
Can anyone suggest a better approach in terms of performance to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let:

```
>>> ld = { 'id' : 0, 'Var': 'Dep1', 'SubVal': 'ABC1||A1B1,ABC2||A2B2,ABC3||A3B3', 'MainValue': 'ABC1'}
```

Your split  + dict solution is roughly (note the `maxsplit` parameter to handle `ABC1||A1B1||B1C1` cases):

```
>>> def parse(d):
...     sub_val = dict(t.split('||', maxsplit=1) for t in ld['SubVal'].split(","))
...     return sub_val[d['MainValue']]

>>> parse(ld)
'A1B1'
```

A benchmarck gives:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: parse(ld))
1.002971081999931
```

You build a dict for a one shot lookup: that's a bit overkill. You can perform a direct lookup for the `MainValue`:

```
>>> def parse_iter(d):
...     mv = d['MainValue']
...     g = (t.split('||', maxsplit=1) for t in d['SubVal'].split(","))
...     return next(v for k, v in g if k == mv)

>>> parse_iter(ld)
'A1B1'
```

It is a little faster:

```
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: parse_iter(ld))
0.8656512869993094
```

A faster approach is to look for the `MainValue` in the the `ld[SubVal]` string and extract the right `SubVal`. (I assume the `MainValue` can't be a `SubVal` or a substring of a `SubVal`).

With a regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> def parse_re(d):
...     pattern = d['MainValue']+"\|\|([^,]+)"
...     return re.search(pattern, d['SubVal']).group(1)

>>> parse_re(ld)
'A1B1'
```

This is around 25 % faster than the first version on the example:

```
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: parse_re(ld))
0.7367669239997667
```

But why not perform the search manually?

```
>>> def parse_search(d):
...     s = d['SubVal']
...     mv = d['MainValue']
...     i = s.index(mv) + len(mv) + 2 # after the ||
...     j = s.index(",", i)
...     return s[i:j]

>>> parse_search(ld)
'A1B1'
```

This version is around 60% faster than the first version (on the given example):

```
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: parse_search(ld))
0.3840863969999191
```

(If the `MainValue` can be a `SubVal`, you can check if there is a comma before the `MainValue` or `SubVal` starts with `MainValue`.)